# Can't seem to hide my UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I created a subclass of UIImageView that I need to re-use all over my app. It is a progress bar that looks like a football. 2 of its methods are:

```
-(void)showFootball {
    self.hidden = NO;
    // other code
}

-(void)hideFootball {
    self.hidden = YES;
}
```

and when the subclass initWithCoder I include this:

```
self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cristiano.png"];
self.hidden = YES;
```

When I include this subclass into my project, and put it on the storyboard, I have a spot where I say

```
[self.soccerBallTimer show];
```

and of course it appears on the screen. But when I say

```
[self.soccerBallTimer hide];
```

it does not disappear. I have also tried thing inside the subclass like

```
self.image = nil;
```

and that also no helps. Any ideas?

edit: My init is like this:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cristiano.png"];
    self.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"init with coder");
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide also code for init method and for adding it to superview?

Comment: The code for the init method is just the UIImage imageNamed stuff that I pasted above, and I just added it to the superview by placing a UIImageView on the storyboard, setting it to hidden, and then changing its class to the name of my custom subclass of UIImageView

Comment: I put the init inside initWithCoder as mentioned above too, not sure if there's a better place.

Comment: -(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cristianopng"];
    self.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"init with coder");
    return self;
}

Comment: This was a threading issue, I just made it use the main thread and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should remove it from superview (you can do this with animation)
and re-add when you call 'show'

Comment: Oh yes I tried this - inside the subclass's "hide" method I added     [self removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"removing from superview");
 but it still doesn't matter (and the message DOES write to console)

Comment: Maybe you added your imageview into superview several times. did you check this?